# avahi-daemon not setting up

Tags: 18.04, dns, services, avahi

For the last week or two I've been getting a package installation failure when I update Ubuntu 18.04. The following text appears in the Details window:

```
Setting up gnome-session-flashback (1:3.28.0-1ubuntu1.1) ...
gnome-session-flashback.target is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.7-3.1ubuntu1.1) ...
Job for avahi-daemon.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status avahi-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript avahi-daemon, action "restart" failed.
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2018-09-15 12:20:04 NZST; 5ms ago
  Process: 25493 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25493 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."

Sep 15 12:18:35 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Service "graham-desktop" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::75a:34e8:b08f:56e3.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop avahi-daemon[25493]: avahi-daemon 0.7 exiting.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 15 12:20:04 graham-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 installed avahi-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried creating an avahi username and group (already exists). I don't want to do a complete reinstall, any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this? I'm also running into this problem now.

Comment: Never found an answer to this. I uninstalled avahi-daemon without apparent consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/316715/removing-the-avahi-daemon-on-ubuntu)  and wurlyfan's comment, best option may be to uninstall avahi-daemon.